# Do any IP cameras implement the UPnP Digital Security Camera profile?

Tags: upnp, ip-camera

I'm trying to find an IP camera that allows me to operate it via UPnP. The UPnP forum provides a Digital Security Camera profile:

http://upnp.org/specs/ha/digitalsecuritycamera/

However, I have not been able to find an IP camera that implements this profile, which would allow a uniform method of controlling different IP cameras. Most IP cameras appear to implement UPnP for discovery purposes only, with the user having to retrieve the presentation URL for the device and then control the camera via the manufacturer's web UI.

The UPnP forum list of certified products does not contain any such devices, and the websites of most IP camera manufacturers are vague about what UPnP services they provide (if not explicitly stating that they only support device discovery).

Has anyone come across any IP cameras which support the Digital Security Camera profile and it's associated services?

Comment: I don't know any cameras, I know that my own software supports it (a video recorder/streaming application) but it is untested because I can't find anything to test it with. So if anyone knows software that does this...?

Answer (score -1):

I know this is an old question, but I came across it in a search and thought I'd share what I know.

I own two D-Link DCS-5010L cameras.  The documentation for the camera doesn't specify specifically which UPnP services the camera supports.  Here's a link to the User's Manual: 
http://www.dlink.com/-/media/Consumer_Products/DCS/DCS%205010L/Manual/DCS_5010L_A1_Manual_v1_00_WW.pdf

On page 47 it says it supports "UPnP Port Forwarding".  UPnP only appears six times in the User's Guide.

I can tell you that it supports email of images of video, pan / tilt, and video sharing.  Sorry, I know that's pretty general information, and it seemed like you were looking for some specific answers.  I googled it and searched around, I couldn't find anything listing the specific UPnP services supported.  My guess is, you might need to contact the different camera vendors.  It might give you a good start, if you're still looking for the info four years after you posted the question.  :-)